# Zip file attachment in memory before emailing

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a new requirement to zip attachments (individually, not into a group) before sending them. The code I'm currently using is, I think, typical:

```
    for (final File attachment : this.files()) {
        final BodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        final DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachment);
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachmentPart.setFileName(attachment.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
    }
```

I would like to compress the file in memory rather than hitting the disk. Unfortunately, on `MimeBodyPart`, the only ways I see to attach a file are with `attachFile()` and `setDataHandler()`. `attachFile()` only works on files already on disk, taking either a `File` or a `String` filename parameter.

`DataHandler` is my other option. One constructor takes a `DataSource`, but the `FileDataSource` implementation doesn't have a compress option (not really surprising). Another constructor lets me pass in an `Object` and a MIME type, but I won't really have an in-memory object, just a `ZipOutputStream`.

So how do I do this? I can fall back on writing a temp file to disk, but I'd really rather not. Should I be trying to write my own `FileCompressionDataSource` implementation? How else might this be approached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html).

Comment: Sweet! Not sure how I missed that, but it's much cleaner than implementing my own DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it in memory might be to use a `MimeBodyPart` and a custom `DataContentHandler`implementation that knows how to convert your object to bytes.